# Symfony Process doesn't execute command

Tags: php, symfony, command-line, process, symfony-process

From a controller method, I want to run a Symfony command, in the background.

```
public function collaboratorsSendInvitationsAction($company_id)
{
    $process = new Process(
        'php ' .  $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/console nd:company send-invitations --id ' . $company_id
    );
    $process->start();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('collaborators_list', [
        'company_id' => $company_id,
    ]);
}
```

The process seems to work because if I execute `$process->getPid();` I get a pid, but the command is not executed.

I have investigated, made several tests, and I arrive at the following result:
When I comment line 290 of the class [Process.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L290) (`$this->status = self::STATUS_STARTED;`) then the command is executed. If no, nothing happens.

Has anyone ever come across this problem? What can cause this? I specify that I use Symfony 2.8.28, and PHP 7.1.10. The problem is found on MacOS and Ubuntu Server.

When I dump the process and execute the manually displayed command, everything works.

Comment: If the process is executed, maybe it is not working properly. Did you try logging some debug messages in it?

Comment: @jerkan I can't debug, PHP is not executed in the process :(

Comment: I opened an issue : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25120